# c# httpwebrequest POST and GET methods (with cookieContainer) c#

Tags: c#, cookiecontainer

I'm trying to login on a xbox live page, and got some problems with that, have no idea why, I think I set everything properly... here is my code

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://account.xbox.com/en-US/PaymentAndBilling/RedeemCode");
Request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
//Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);

Response.Close();

HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.live.com/");
getRequest.Method = "POST";
getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

string postData = String.Format("login=/*dd*/&passwd=/*pass*/");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
getResponse.Cookies = cookies;
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream());
string sourceCode = sr1.ReadToEnd();
richTextBox1.Text = sourceCode;
sr1.Close();
```

I would really apprieciate any help, or any info where can I find some explain of cookiecontainers, http protocols in c# etc.... as it's my first program working with WebRequests, really thank u for help in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: When I put sourceCode into browser, it say's that I should have enable cookies and javascript...
But it doesn't even return the code I want (the page after login)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're going to hate me, but if I had any choice I would not use HttpwebResponse, I would use http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

It's so easy because it uses the full blown browser instead of needing to maintain cookies.  And if you need to run it interactively, or without the gui you can use SimpleDriver()

Comment: HttpWebResponse is much faster, and I saw one guy which login on this site through httpWebResponse, he said he can sell me this code for 20$... So maybe I could find someone smarter here

Comment: @Propert yes faster and less memory, but not nearly as easy or as powerful.  I'd love to see HttpWebResponse mimick asp requests when interacting with grids and forms

Comment: @Propert not to mention filling and solving captacha along with a lot of other really nice items

Comment: this is not a solution for his/her problem.